# Pandas: Truth Value of a Series is Ambiguous Despite Using Bitwise

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find all rows in my DataFrame (`combined_df`) where the `Title` column is not any of `"Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"`.  Here's my attempt:

```
combined_df[~ (combined_df.Title in ["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"])]
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've looked around on SO and most answers say to use bit-wise operators (`&, |, ~`) so that's what I did above.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Edit:

When I do this:

```
combined_df["Title"].value_counts()
```

I get back:

```
 Mr              757
 Miss            260
 Mrs             197
 Master           61
 Rev               8
 Dr                8
 Col               4
 Ms                2
 Major             2
 Mlle              2
 Mme               1
 Don               1
 Dona              1
 Jonkheer          1
 Sir               1
 Lady              1
 Capt              1
 the Countess      1
Name: Title, dtype: int64
```

But when I do this:

```
len(combined_df[(~combined_df.Title.isin(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]))])
```

I get back:

```
1309
```

Which is the full size of my dataset, so it hasn't filtered out any rows...

Comment: Try `combined_df.Title.isin(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"])`

Comment: @Zero Hmm when I do `combined_df[~ (combined_df.Title.isin(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]))]`, I get back rows only containing those specified Titles...

Comment: @bclayman are you sure you have the ~ operator? It's working for me..

Comment: @FelipeTrenk Yeah, just double checked.  Added more info to question to clarify

Comment: Check for the top words and `(["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master"]`, if they are leading or trailing spaces in your actual data..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
combined_df = combined_df[~combined_df['Title'].isin(['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss', 'Master'])]
```